# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException error when displaying database values in listview

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I am new to android mobile development. I have created a database called EmployeeList, which is inside my Assets folder. I want to get the data from there and display it in a list view format in my activity. The application keeps crashing and I don't know why. Thank you for the help.

> It is a mix of sample code found online and my own.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by ahadagali on 6/15/2017.
 */

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "EmployeeList";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

    public Cursor fetchAll() {
        Cursor myCursor;
        myCursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from EmployeeList", null);
        //myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (myDataBase != null) {
            myCursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from EmployeeList", null);
        }
        return myCursor;
    }

}
```

**activityThree.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.io.IOException;

public class activityThree extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;

    TextView name;
    TextView phoneNum;
    TextView jobPos;
    TextView availability;

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_three);

        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_fullName);
        phoneNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_phoneNum);
        jobPos = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_jobPosition);
        availability = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_availability);

        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }

        Cursor AllEmployees = myDbHelper.fetchAll();



        AllEmployees.moveToFirst();
        while (!AllEmployees.isAfterLast()){
            AllEmployees.moveToNext();
        }

        String[] from = {AllEmployees.getString(1), AllEmployees.getString(2), AllEmployees.getString(3), AllEmployees.getString(4)};
        int [] to = {R.id.tv_fullName, R.id.tv_phoneNum, R.id.tv_jobPosition, R.id.tv_availability};
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, AllEmployees, from, to, 0);
        ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

**activity_three.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_fullName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#4bb6d6"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_phoneNum"
        android:text="734"
        android:textColor="#b30000"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_jobPosition"
        android:text="Job Position"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_availability"
        android:text="Availability"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Error Log**

```
06-15 07:09:00.579 27137-27165/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-15 07:09:00.579 27137-27165/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-15 07:09:00.579 27137-27165/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
06-15 07:09:00.579 27137-27165/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
06-15 07:09:00.591 1296-1406/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:00.631 1296-1406/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:00.695 27137-27137/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
06-15 07:09:00.782 1540-1598/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/.MainActivity: +678ms
06-15 07:09:00.818 1296-1296/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
06-15 07:09:00.969 1540-1598/system_process D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
06-15 07:09:01.903 1655-1655/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
06-15 07:09:01.909 1296-3089/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:01.933 1296-3089/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:01.973 1296-3089/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:03.531 1655-1655/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
06-15 07:09:03.536 27137-27137/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-15 07:09:04.350 1540-2981/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/.activityTwo (has extras)} from uid 10073 on display 0
06-15 07:09:04.389 1296-1336/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:04.416 1296-1337/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:04.452 1296-1337/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
06-15 07:09:04.588 1540-1598/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/.activityTwo: +232ms
06-15 07:09:04.591 27137-27137/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-15 07:09:04.591 27137-27137/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-15 07:09:06.247 1540-1554/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/.activityThree} from uid 10073 on display 0
06-15 07:09:06.280 27137-27137/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-15 07:09:06.281 27137-27137/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag, PID: 27137
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag.activityThree}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
                                                                                     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                                                                                     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                                     at com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag.activityThree.onCreate(activityThree.java:68)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
06-15 07:09:06.282 1540-2982/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/.activityThree
06-15 07:09:06.286 1540-2982/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.ahadagali.fivesdyag/.activityTwo
06-15 07:09:06.294 1302-1422/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xa6403a40) throttle end: throttle time(43)
06-15 07:09:06.328 1296-1337/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
```

Comment: Please post your logcat errors.

Comment: Just made an edit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause is:**

> Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4
>   requested, with a size of 4

Change your index request to 3 (max).
Indexes are zero based.

Probably on this line of your code:

```
String[] from = {AllEmployees.getString(1), AllEmployees.getString(2), AllEmployees.getString(3), AllEmployees.getString(4)};
```

Try 0 through 3 (insted of 1 through 4). I'm guessing you only have a max of four columns or something.

EDIT
Try commenting changing the following code (comment the lines that I've commented below)
I believe you are iterating to the end of the data so your cursor is past all the data before you try to read.

```
AllEmployees.moveToFirst();
      //  while (!AllEmployees.isAfterLast()){
        //    AllEmployees.moveToNext();
       // }

        String[] from = {AllEmployees.getString(1), AllEmployees.getString(2), AllEmployees.getString(3), AllEmployees.getString(4)};
        int [] to = {R.id.tv_fullName, R.id.tv_phoneNum, R.id.tv_jobPosition, R.id.tv_availability};
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, AllEmployees, from, to, 0);
        ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**EDIT 2**

Try replacing your code (following 3 lines) with mine):

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, AllEmployees, from, to, 0);
        ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**new code**

```
  String[]values={"Android","iOS","Windows Phone","Other Stuff"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,values);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If everything works then try the following code after the working code (which will add the values from your database):

```
while (!AllEmployees.isAfterLast()){
               AllEmployees.moveToNext();
               adapter.add(AllEmployees.getString(0);
           }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged (); // updates the list in UI
```

Only add this 2nd part after the other part works.
This isn't exactly correct, but after this you should be able to work through it.

Comment: I tried 0 through 3, but it is still giving me the same error of CursorIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: Since I can't run the code, it's a bit difficult to tell, but that could mean there is no data in your table.  Do you have any data in the table? If not,the cursor itself may be empty.  Not sure how that works but this is a guess. EDIT - Wait, you are possibly reading after you've iterated through all the data.  Do the MoveFirst() call and then move the lines that iterate through the cursor out of there. These lines ---Move or comment for a test.  
while (!AllEmployees.isAfterLast()){
            AllEmployees.moveToNext();
        }
I think they are moving you to the end of the data.

Comment: I tried that and now the app doesn't crash anymore! But there is no error now. Just a blank screen instead of the list view. No errors in the logcat either.

Comment: First, at least upvote me. I got you one step closer and actually answered the question. :) Now, you want the values to show up in a spinner (droplist) right?  I have code to show you how to do that.  Let me think about how to get the code to you.  I'll try to post a quick code snippet to my answer.